# Did you ever use ObRegisterCallbacks on x86?

Tags: windows, x86, driver

I am trying to use `ObRegisterCallbacks` to prevent my app being terminated.

in windows 7 x64 system, it works well as my plan.

but in windows 7 x86 system, there are some problems.

I have to link my driver with `/INTEGRITYCHECK` linker option, or I couldn't use ObRegisterCallbacks function. It returned `ACCESS_DENIED`.

but if I build it with `/INTEGRITYCHECK` linker option, I couldn't load my driver.

when I call `StartService()`, it returned `ERROR_INVALID_IMAGE_HASH`.

Of course, I had signed my driver after build. so my driver file had a digital signature on binary.

However it still returned `ERROR_INVALID_IMAGE_HASH`.

and if I built with same sources for x64 platform, it works fine.

furthermore, if I boot my PC(x86) with Test Boot Mode , it works well too.

I am wondering that is possible to use `ObRegisterCallbacks` on x86 system ( not test boot mode ).

Any reply will be appreciated.

Comment: Have you double-checked that the signature is in fact valid?

Comment: hm? how can i do that double-check? please tell me about that way of checking.

Comment: by the way, as the same step, I succeed it on x64.

Comment: signtool verify /v /kp foo.sys, according to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg487543

Answer (score 1):

It works for x86 system you need to sign your driver using certificate , Testsigning does not work so make sure you have certificate using makecert tool.
use signtool to sign your driver withthe certificate you created